# External webservice "Internal Error"

Tags: web-services, request

Okey so after searching for 3 hours and trying various options, I no longer have any clue how to solve this...

**The situation:**
Our nationwide packet deliverer (Die Post) offers a webservice for checking if an address exists.
I contacted them, received username and password for the application as well as the .wsdl-file.
I made a service reference to the downloaded file and can use the classes without problems.

**Now the problem:**
We have 2 other webservices which the previous programer set up with authentication and everything, I just copy pasted the code from one of the services and set everything to current one, but when I try to get a response, I always get an error (Internal Error), with no more information.
I found a way to get the last request and the only difference from the request to the one in the SoapUI (which works perfectly fine) is that, instead of "`<soapenv:Header/>`" it is
`<s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://post.ch/AdressCheckerExtern/V4-01-00</Action>
  </s:Header>`

The current code is:

```
 // Create Request
PostAdressChecker.AdressCheckerRequestType adrRequest = new PostAdressChecker.AdressCheckerRequestType()
{
    Street = strStrasse,
    HouseNbr = strHausnummer,
    Zip = strPlz,
    Town = strOrt,
    Params = new PostAdressChecker.AdressCheckerRequestTypeParams()
    {
        CallUser = "TU_99660_0001",
        SearchLanguage = "1",
        MaxRows = "10",
        SearchType = "10"
    }
};

BasicHttpBinding basicBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
{
    ReaderQuotas = { MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue },
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
};

PostAdressChecker.ACHePortTypeClient client;
client = new PostAdressChecker.ACHePortTypeClient(basicBinding, new EndpointAddress(strUrl));
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new PostSigningEndpointBehavior(strUsername, strPassword));            
SoapTracer RequestInterceptor = new SoapTracer();
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(RequestInterceptor);

try
{
    PostAdressChecker.AdressCheckerResponseType adrResponse = client.AdrCheckerExterne(adrRequest);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    strError = ex.ToString();
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to debug/solve this?
Thank you very much and best regards

Answer (score 0):

in perl I do it like this. maybe this can give you some inspiration ...

```perl
sub clientFactory {
     my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new('etc/adrCheckerExterne-V4-01-00.wsdl');
     $wsdl->importDefinitions('etc/adrCheckerExterne-V4-01-00.xsd');
     $wsdl->importDefinitions('etc/adrCheckerTypes-V4-01-00.xsd');
     my $basic_auth = sub {
         my ($request, $trace) = @_;
         my $authorization = 'Basic '.
             b64_encode "$adrCheckerUser:$adrCheckerPassword";
         $request->header(Authorization => $authorization );
         my $ua = $trace->{user_agent};
         $ua->request($request);
     };
     return $wsdl->compileClient(
         'AdrCheckerExterne',
         transport_hook => $basic_auth,
         aync => 1,
     );
};

my $client = clientFactory;

my $check = $client->(
    Params => {
        MaxRows => 100,
        CallUser => $adrCheckerUser,
        SearchLanguage => 1,
        SearchType => 1
    },
    FirstName => $first_name,
    Name => ${last_name},
    Street => ${street},
    HouseNbr => ${nr},
    Zip => ${zip},
    Town => ${town},
    HouseKey => 0,
    PboxAddress => 0,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `HouseKey = 0` to your `adrRequest`. This is a required input - you can just set it to 0 if you do not know it. Otherwise the service will return an error.